# Put csv data into separate columns in Sheets with appendRow

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet that collects data when an I.D. badge barcode is scanned. The data from the barcode is csv. By default, scanning puts the whole csv (name,phone_number,department) into one cell at the end of the sheet. I want the name, phone_number, and department to go into separate cells. How can I separate the comma separated values?

```
function appendARow()  // Appends a new row with data scanned from i.d. badge
{ 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1' // Name of current sheet
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    var dataCell = sheet.getRange('A1');
    var newData = dataCell.getValue();
    sheet.appendRow([newData]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)  the string by `,`:

```
var newData = dataCell.getValue().split(",");
sheet.appendRow(newData);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks for helping a newbie.